# C++: Check if string is a valid MD5 hex hash

Tags: c++, regex, string, md5

How can I properly check if a std::string is a valid MD5 hex hash on C++?

Keep in mind that I want to avoid looping and I can't use boost libraries nor regex from C++11.

Comment: lets try to answer "what is valid md5 hash"?

Comment: You can test whether it's hex characters very easily: test if it contains any characters outside `0-9A-F`. Testing whether it's specifically a hex hash seems infeasible.

Comment: @Barmar md5 hash first of all contains 128 bits, which can be differently presented via printable characters, one of them actually hex notation, which uses 0-9a-fA-F symbols, so any 32 chars string with this symbols can be supposed as "valid md5 hash", but I'm not sure that OP needs that

Comment: You can check if a character is a valid hex character using `isxdigit`. You can check the length... by checking the length. What else do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
if (value.size() == 32 && value.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF") == -1)
```

Or since cluracan mentions `isxdigit` in a comment, this might be faster:

```
if (value.size() == 32 && std::find_if(value.begin(), value.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isxdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }) == value.end())
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that MD5 is 128bit value which is 16bytes. It is usually written in 32char hex string for human convenience.

If you do not need to 'see' your md5 value - keep it as 16bytes - this way you do not need any fancy structures like std::string to store it. Just 16 byte array. You do not have to validate it either as everything you can store in 16byte array is also valid MD5 value ;-)